# How to create generic xpath out of this dynamic xpath?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping

While web scraping, I came across an element (which I have to click a number of times) which changes xpath. Below I have copied a few:

```
xpath = //*[@id="course-list"]/ul[2]/li[9]/a

xpath = //*[@id="course-list"]/ul[2]/li[9]/a

xpath = //*[@id="course-list"]/ul[2]/li[10]/a

xpath = //*[@id="course-list"]/ul[2]/li[11]/a
```

How can I make a generic Xpath from this info?

Comment: Hard to tell. Is it always the last `li`?

Comment: @choroba  yes it's always the last but li[-1] doesn't work

Comment: It doesn't, but `li[last()]` should.

Answer (score 0):

To get the last node from a node list, use the `last()` function:

```
xpath = //*[@id="course-list"]/ul[2]/li[last()]/a
```